# nginx not serving my error_page

Tags: nginx, custom-error-pages

I have a Sinatra application hosted with Unicorn, and nginx in front of it. When the Sinatra application errors out (returns 500), I'd like to serve a static page, rather than the default "Internal Server Error". I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name *.example.com;
  root /home/deploy/www-frontend/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5;
    proxy_read_timeout 240;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4701/;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
}
```

The error_page directive is there, and I have sudo'd as www-data (Ubuntu) and verified I can `cat` the file, thus it's not a permission problem. With the above config file, and `service nginx reload`, the page I receive on error is still the same "Internal Server Error".

What's my error?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`error_page` handles errors that are generated by nginx. By default, nginx will return whatever the proxy server returns regardless of http status code.

What you're looking for is [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors)

> This directive decides if nginx will intercept responses with HTTP
>   status codes of 400 and higher.
>
> By default all responses will be sent as-is from the proxied server.
>
> If you set this to on then nginx will intercept status codes that are
>   explicitly handled by an error_page directive. Responses with status
>   codes that do not match an error_page directive will be sent as-is
>   from the proxied server.

Comment: I knew it was a question of RTFM. Thanks for taking the time to provide a great answer!

Comment: Just a quick note to a 4 years old response  - now `proxy_intercept_errors` works for errors equal or greater to 300.

Comment: After setting this directive on, the custom error page gets enabled, but custom response headers sent from the upstream are getting dropped. Any ideas how to resolve this part?

Answer (score 23):

You can set proxy_intercept_errors especially for that location

```
location /some/location {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5;
    proxy_read_timeout 240;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4701/;
    proxy_intercept_errors on; # see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors

    error_page 400 500 404 ... other statuses ... =200 /your/path/for/custom/errors;
}
```

and you can set instead 200 other status what you need

Comment: Using `proxy_intercept_errors;` (without argument) is no longer valid in current nginx. Use `proxy_intercept_errors on;` instead.

Comment: Quick question about the semantics here... setting `proxy_intercept_errors` to `on` means that the custom page is returned, and setting to `off` means the nginx page is returned, correct?

Comment: I am using a FASTCGI  even If I turn proxy_intercept_errors on it still won't intercept the error. It won't even intercept 404 errors.

Answer (score 5):

People who are using FastCGI as their upstream need this parameter turned on

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

For my PHP application, I am using it in my upstream configuration block

```
 location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    fastcgi_pass   php-upstream; 
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 500 /500.html;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Stephen [in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344414/intercepting-upstream-error-with-nginx), using `proxy_intercept_errors on;` can work.
Though in my case, as seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29344415/6622232), using `uwsgi_intercept_errors on;` did the trick...