# intercepting upstream error with nginx

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, http-error

My app runs with nginx and uwsgi (python). My aim is to drop a connection (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300344/terminating-a-uwsgi-worker-programmatically)) e.g. when the python app decides to do so.

Is there a nginx parameter to "intercept" upstream errors similar to `proxy_intercept_errors`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031818/show-a-custom-503-page-if-upstream-is-down),

My nginx config:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass                myapp;
    include                   uwsgi_params;

    uwsgi_buffering           on;
    uwsgi_buffer_size         8k;

    uwsgi_connect_timeout     800;

    uwsgi_read_timeout        800;
    uwsgi_send_timeout        800;

    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
    error_page 420 =444 @foo;
}

location @foo {
    return 444;
}
```

I tried all possible combinations I could think of with/without `proxy_intercept_errors` and `error_page` but no matter how I configure nginx, when I return `420 Enhance your calm` (or any other error code, apparently) it gets passed directly to the client.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/279109/error-page-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-nginx-upstream-directive) suggests using `proxy_next_upstream` but that implies using `proxy_pass` rather than `uwsgi_pass`. I need to use `uwsgi_pass` because I need certain parameters passed to the python app.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the answer is simpler than I thought - use the [uwsgi_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_intercept_errors) directive.

Firstly, from the upstream app (in my case python) return `444`.

Secondly, configure nginx as follows:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass                myapp;
    include                   uwsgi_params;
    [...]

    uwsgi_intercept_errors  on;
    error_page 444 @drop;
}

location @drop {
    return 444;
}
```